# How to run the main function in lean 4?

Tags: lean4

I am following the [lean 4 tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/whatIsLean.html) and see a main function as follows:

```
-- Defines a function that takes a name and produces a greeting.
def getGreeting (name : String) := s!"Hello, {name}! Isn't Lean great?"

-- The `main` function is the entry point of your program.
-- Its type is `IO Unit` because it can perform `IO` operations (side effects).
def main : IO Unit :=
  -- Define a list of names
  let names := ["Sebastian", "Leo", "Daniel"]

  -- Map each name to a greeting
  let greetings := names.map getGreeting

  -- Print the list of greetings
  for greeting in greetings do
    IO.println greeting
```

I am not sure how to run the `main` function. It's not in the FAQ. I tried to call it from the command line (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
lean 1_whats.lean
```

It gives no result. The VS code IDE (with lean4 support installed following the prompt) does not seem to show anything in `All Messages`. I tried to add a separate line with just `main`, which causes an error on the preceding `for` line

> invalid 'do' notation, expected type is not available

Obviously, this is really a beginner question.

*How to run the main function in lean 4?*

Comment: Is that indentation intended?

Comment: @Trebor I assume not since the original example is not indented.  Copy and paste gone wrong?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the indentation issue. Just edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may extract C source and compile it:

```bash
$ cat hello.lean 
def main := IO.println "Hello, World!"
$ lean -c hello.c hello.lean 
$ leanc hello.c -o hello
$ ./hello 
Hello, World!
```

Or pass `--run` option just as in Lean 3:

```bash
$ lean --run hello.lean 
Hello, World!
```

There is also [Lake](https://github.com/leanprover/lake) [described in tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/quickstart.html):

```bash
$ mkdir hello
$ cd hello
$ lake init hello
$ lake build
...
$ ./build/bin/hello
Hello, world!
```

Compiling or `--run`-ing by hand multiple interconnected files is a way harder. Suppose we have something like this:

```bash
$ cat test.lean 
def test := "HELLO"
$ cat hello.lean 
import test

def main := IO.println test
```

`lean --run hello.lean` will fail at this time:

```bash
$ lean --run hello.lean 
hello.lean:1:0: error: unknown package 'test'
hello.lean:3:12: error: unknown identifier 'IO.println'
hello.lean:3:12: error: unknown constant 'sorryAx'
```

For first, you need to properly set up your `LEAN_PATH`. There should be at least `path-to-your-lean4-directory/lib/lean` and your working directory:

```bash
$ echo $LEAN_PATH
/path-to-my-lean4-directory/lib/lean/:/path-to-my-working-directory
```

After `import test` Lean will look up for `test.olean` file in `LEAN_PATH` (and for directories named `test`). So you need to create these .olean files:

```bash
$ lean -o test.olean test.lean
```

And now you can run `hello.lean`:

```bash
$ lean --run hello.lean 
HELLO
```

At this moment we can also extract C code for both files:

```bash
$ lean -c test.c test.lean 
$ lean -c hello.c hello.lean
```

And compile them exactly as you compile C. So you may pass `test.c` and `hello.c` directly to `leanc` (which is wrapper around `clang`):

```bash
$ leanc test.c hello.c -o hello
```

Or firstly generate object files and then link them together:

```bash
$ leanc test.c -c -o test.o
$ leanc hello.c -c -o hello.o
$ leanc test.o hello.o -o hello
```

Or link them into a static/dynamic library if you want:

```bash
$ ar rcs libtest.a test.o hello.o
$ leanc libtest.a -o hello
$ ./hello 
HELLO
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, can the first method work if you have multiple interconnected lean files, or do you just have to move to Lake then?  Also is there something like `lean --run` for Lake projects, where you can run your code without compiling first?

Comment: @JasonRute yes, it can, and `lean --run` can work with Lake projects. I edited my answer to explain this.

Comment: There is also something called [scripts](https://github.com/leanprover/lake#scripts) in Lake, but I never used this feature.

Comment: in 2024. `lake` places build artifacts inside `.lake/build`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to first be clear, in Lean a `main` function is an entry point to use *Lean as a programming language* with input and output, and a `main` function is a common feature in many compiled programming languages.  If you are interested in using Lean as a theorem prover, or using Lean interactively (by say executing code with `#eval`), then you don't need a `main` function, and I would point you to [Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/title_page.html).

### Method 1: Building a Lean 4 (code) project using Lake

Now, how to compile a Lean 4 project to run `main`?  Note that Lean 4 is compiled, and the tool to both make your project and compile it is `lake`.  There are instructions [here](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/setup.html#lake) but they might be a bit confusing.

To make a new lean code project, do `lake new <project_name>` to make a new project directory, or if you already have a project directory, do `lake init <project_name>` inside that directory.

For example, `lake new my_test_project` makes a directory `my_test_project` which can be opened in vs code and adds the following files:

```
.gitignore
MyTestProject.lean
lakefile.lean
lean-toolchain
Main.lean
```

Note, `lake new` and `lake init` always add this code which comes pre-populated with a simple hello world program.  In particular, `Main.lean` contains the `main` function.

To build your project, run `lake build`.  This will add the following files:

```
build/
  bin/
    my_test_project
    my_test_project.trace
  ir/
    ...
  lib/
    ...
```

If you run the bin file, `build/bin/my_test_project` you will get the output:

```
Hello, world!
```

A few more notes:

- See [here](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/setup.html#lake) for advice on how to structure the files in your project.  But it seems out of date with the current way Lake sets up the directory (namely with a `Main.lean` file).
- I don't do much development in Lean 4, but I think if you were going down this route, you could set up build tasks in VS Code to make the build and run steps go faster.

#### Method 2: Run a one-off lean file with `lean --run`

If you have a file such as the one you posted in your question which has both a `main` function and doesn't import other things, then it is possible to run it with `lean --run <filename>.lean`.  If my memory serves me correctly, this can make the code run slower since it is not compiled (but that only matters if you are doing heavy computation).

Edit: See siegment's answer for how to compile a one-off lean file directly.

Note: At least right now I can't do `lean --run Main.lean` on the `Main.lean` example from Lake, since `Main.lean` imports other stuff.  That gives me strange errors.  (I don't know if that is intended or a bug.)

Edit: See siegment's answer for how to make `lean --run` work with more complicated projects (such as those coming from Lake).