# How to run lean4 with mathlib manually

Tags: lean4

I have a file which contents are:

```
import Mathlib.Data.Rat.Basic
```

I save it as file.lean in a lean project
and run it like this

```
lean --run .\file.lean
```

I get

```
.\file.lean:1:0: error: unknown package 'Mathlib'
```

but if I do

```
> ls .\lake-packages\    


    Directory: C:\fakepath\mathematics_in_lean\lake-packages


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        30.10.2023     01:25                aesop
d-----        30.10.2023     00:33                Cli
d-----        30.10.2023     01:24                mathlib
d-----        30.10.2023     01:24                proofwidgets
d-----        30.10.2023     01:25                Qq
d-----        30.10.2023     01:25                std
```

So it should work, right?

I don't want it to run on vscode, just run on the terminal.

Comment: If you want to run it really manually, you should add your package to the LEAN_PATH by hand (as well as standard libraries, see https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1392/310 or https://leanprover-community.github.io/toolchain.html); but most likely Lake will be enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. It was crucial for me to run Lean code using terminal. After trial and error, this is the only way I've managed to do that:

1. Go to the directory where your *.lean file is:

```
cd /path/to/lean_file/
```

2. Run your *.lean file using this command:

```
lake env lean file_name.lean
```

This command works slow, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

To build a single file in a Lean project from the command line, you should be using `lake build Path.To.File`, which would build `Path/To/File.lean`.